# Create a new images with smaller images using PIL

Tags: python, image-manipulation, python-imaging-library

I am writing a photomosaic python application.

I want to know how to create the final image (.jpg) using multiple smaller images from a pool of images with Python/PIL. I have the order in which I want the various images to be in a 2-dimensional list.

Answer (score 0):

Documented on the first PIL documenation page (paste() method):

http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm

In addition:

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/128112
http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/22566-overlaying-transparent-images-pil